# jsdoc how break/close a tag

Tags: tags, jsdoc3

I would like insert a description between two example

```
/**
*@method ChangeItem
*@example
*oMenu.ChangeItem("menu.enable_all",{enable:true});
*oMenu.ChangeItem("menu",label:"",icon:align:"after",text:ICO.arrow_down}});
*
*If I write description here, it appear into the first example
*
*@example  
*oMenu.ChangeItem("menu.enable_all",{enable:true});
*oMenu.ChangeItem("menu",{label:"",icon:{align:"after",text:ICO.arrow_down}});
*/
```

How can I close the first tag?

I tried to use the tag description but it go on the top of the first example
Sorry for my english and for the stupid question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done like that, I have not tried but you could put `@description` in front of your description (but this might not put your description in the right place).

I think the cleaner approach would be to have one `@example` block where you put code comments like

```
oMenu.ChangeItem("menu.enable_all",{enable:true});
oMenu.ChangeItem("menu",label:"",icon:align:"after",text:ICO.arrow_down}});

// Example 2
oMenu.ChangeItem("menu.enable_all",{enable:true});
oMenu.ChangeItem("menu",{label:"",icon:{align:"after",text:ICO.arrow_down}});
```